# Recyclerview change textview color on click changing color of other textview also

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have recyclerview in my activity and binding it with custom layout. I have click listener on textview. when i click on textview i am changing the color of textview.

**My Problem is that when i click on 1st textview than it changes the color of 13th textview also. I want multiple selection of items.**

here is my code

Recyclerview

```
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/recycler_view_test_QNo"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="58dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="7dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="7dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="7dp"

    android:background="@color/unVisited" />
```

Custom Adapter

```
public class TestAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<TestAdapter.viewHolder> {

private ArrayList<String> questionNo;

Context _context;
public TestAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<String> questionNo){
    _context=context;
    this.questionNo = questionNo;
    this._callback=callback;
}

@Override
public viewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

    @SuppressLint("InflateParams") View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.custom_test,null);
    return new viewHolder(view);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final viewHolder holder, int position) {

    holder.textView.setText(questionNo.get(position));

}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return questionNo.size();
}

class viewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener{

    TextView textView;

    viewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        textView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_QuesNo_custom);
        textView.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        textView.setTextColor(Color.RED);
    }
}
}
```

custom_test.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tv_QuesNo_custom"
    android:layout_width="42dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="5dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="50dp"

    android:gravity="center"
    android:textSize="30sp"
     />
</LinearLayout>
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Try to put Click listener inside the onBindView holder.

Comment: i tried it but not working

Answer (score 0):

First initialise
Integer selectedPosition = -1;

Then in onBindViewHolder

```
public void onBindViewHolder(final ViewHolder holder, final int position) {
        holder.textView.setText(questionNo.get(position));

        holder.textView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                selectedPosition = position;
                notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        });
        if(selectedPosition == position){
            holder.textView.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#FF0000"));
        }
        else
        {
            //You can set your color
        }

    }
```

Comment: its working for one item but it want multiple item selected

Comment: First of all, Clearly mention your requirement in the questions itself.Update your question properly.And using the above logic you will get your requirement with some modification.Best of luck

Comment: sorry for that i have mentioned it now.